# Inverse image of differential of the tangent space of a submanifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Let $M, N$ be smooth manifolds, $A \subseteq M$ a submanifold and $f : N \rightarrow M$ a smooth map such that $f^{-1}(A) \subseteq N$ is a submanifold (e.g. f transverse to $A$). Is it true in general that:
$$
\forall y \in f^{-1}(A): (T_yf)^{-1}(T_{f(y)}A) = T_yf^{-1}(A)?
$$
This seems to hold in simple examples I've come up with, but I have no idea how to (dis)prove this in general.

Comment: You should be able to prove this is correct precisely when $f$ is transverse to $A$. Try to make up an example where transversality fails and yet $f^{-1}(A)$ is a submanifold.

Comment: Since this is purely local, this is the sort of thing for which a 1-manifold -- like the graph of a smooth function! -- in 2-space is likely to provide a counterexample if there is one. Can you think of any interesting functions from $\Bbb R $ to itself? Ones where the graph is not transverse to the $x$-axis might be interesting.